Would Canadians like to be a part of the United States as Trump wants?
I'm a European, Belgian. We live in a crazy world. I'm trying to make sense of what happens across the Atlantic.
A few days ago the next president of the United States stated he wanted to incorporate Canada into the United States.

QUESTION: CONCISE FORMULATION | 31/12/2024 12:00

What are the reactions of Canadians to Trump's wish to incorporate
their country into the United States?


In my first version of this post, I wrote a lot of questions instead of one. They still might be useful for a more in-depth answer, so I leave them here:

FIRST FORMULATION | 31/12/2024 11:00
I would like to know: which reactions do Canadians have to this? Which amount of the population agrees, disagrees or is indifferent to this? Is this a debate based on common political ideologies, an economic debate (the argument Trump uses) or is there an emotional love/aversion toward their neighbours? I have little insight into the political mentality or national identity of Canada or their attitude versus their southern neighbors. What kind of background do the proponents and opponents of incorporation in the US have? As far as I know, Canada does now have a "liberal" government, but I don't know the tendency of the opposition parties. Is there a strong fascist tendency like in the United States? How many Canadians are in favor of Trump? Is this a possibility, now or, in the future? How would Canadians react to the force the next president wants to use against their country?

No need to close.  Bona fide question, just like asking what the realities of Trump's Greenland ramblings boil down to.  And... you know, new user and all that:  be nice and don't go out of your way to invent close reasons for new users.   Sheesh.

(although the question would be even better with the "first formulation" paragraph removed entirely, not that it was that bad to being with).  Welcome aboard.

Conveniently we have a recent poll.

Poll suggests 13% of Canadians think Canada should become the 51st American state


The demographic breakdowns show there’s higher support among men, at 19 per cent, compared with only seven per cent of women.


Conservative party supporters came in at 21 per cent, while one in 10 Liberal voters said they were in favour of the idea. The People’s Party of Canada showed the highest level of endorsement among the federal parties, at 25 per cent, while the NDP was the lowest at six per cent.


A full 82 per cent of respondents said they were opposed to the idea. People in the Atlantic provinces, women and Canadians over the age of 55 were least likely to support it.

(The actual poll, rather than coverage of it is here)
Biggest support in Western states, sorry, provinces is still low:

Manitoba 18%
Saskatchewan 18%
Alberta 19%
British Columbia 15%

Not too many undecideds either.
Now, Wexit party, which advocates Alberta leaving Canada had at least one prominent member who was for it.  There is considerable sympathy to Trump (or maybe just Trudeau-hate) amongst some of the West.  But that still does not make it much to the actual platform of Wexit aka Maverick.  Mind you, as Wexit by itself would leave Alberta landlocked and isolated, joining the US would be a somewhat reasonable geopolitical move in that circumstance.
A big part of that rejection is how much Canadians dislike the US health care system, whatever else they find wrong with Canada.
p.s.  I consider "51st state" a technicality, as opposed to joining the US or not.  People probably would complain about that aspect, if the idea in general was getting much traction.  Suggesting each province that joins get its own statehood is unlikely to move the needle much.
p.p.s.  I doubt Trump means much by it (probably even less than Greenland).  He has a tendency to make jokes, sometimes not very diplomatic ones, in order to be "a man of the people" and appeal to his base.  "51st state" is part of that, it's too common a joke about Canadians by Americans and wouldn't be used if he was seriously making diplomatic moves.  Think about it in terms of US domestic politics:  this would skew the US a lot more towards the Democrats than say allowing the District of Columbia to join as a state.  Honestly, if making stupid jokes was the only issue with Trump, no one here would care that much, we'd just be happy not to have elected him.  But in the case of Canada he's again threatening to go back on his word re. NAFTA and its successor trade agreement.

Why just the 51st state? Were there any polls for the 51st through 60th states?

I don't know.  I am not sure it would that much difference.  I assume people are generally answering "should we join the US" and that "just 51st state" is a bit of a put down.  But I think that's a technicality and 51-60 still wouldn't cut the mustard.

It's worth noting that support for the Canadian healthcare system isn't all that great

It is not.  There is plenty that is wrong, not least forbidding out-of-pocket pays for people who can afford it (something France allows, IIRC), making medical tourism a necessity in some cases.  But don't confuse that for anything else than dislike at the US alternative.  If anything, Canadians are blissfully unaware of better nationalized healthcare systems in Europe and only generally compare ours to the US.  Which is detrimental to reforms here, since the counter example sucks so bad.  Though awareness of the UK's NHS is possibly higher, but that's also not a great example, these days.

Interesting (2018) paper comparing Canadian health system to its peers.  Also, keep in mind that we, like the US, are undergoing an opioid crisis and that is sucking resources massively out of the general health system.  People not directly exposed to it have a hard time understanding how 2010+ trends in fentanyl addiction result in young adults with massive, life-altering, permanent disabilities and health problems.  You're talking people with amputations and advanced spinal deformities.

@RickSmith: Indeed, making each province (and territory, including Yukon, NWT, and Nunavut?) a state (with 2 senators each) could significantly change the balance of power between left and right in the US, if this were to happen.  (Or not if Canadian conservative voters voter for US conservative parties, which are typically significantly to the right of Canadian politics.  But in presidential elections would probably overall lean towards Democrat candidates.)  But anyway, I don't think that would be enough to sway most Canadians.  Still, I'd be very interested to see a poll.

A big part of that rejection is how much Canadians dislike the US health care system - except those who actually get to try the American system :-) I’ve tried both in depth and I laugh so hard when I hear someone say the Canadian system is better. So part of the hate for the idea is just plain ignorance.

The US system works A-OK if you're part of the people who have good coverage and access.  Or if you can pay out of pocket.  It's sub-par if you are not.  It's also subpar in terms of costs vs benefit:  it costs about 2x of GPD of what its peers' cost and it delivers less in most country wide health metrics.  But OK, you're entitled to your opinion.  The reason I cite it is because talk to the man on the street here and the 1st thing Canadians criticize is US health care.  2nd:  Gun violence.   3rd:  We also happily criticize US racial relations issues while ignoring ours with native Canadians

There are some in favour, but well short of a majority.
The idea gets more support in Alberta, Saskatchewan, Manitoba and Ontario where about 30% are favourable to the idea, with support stronger among the young.
Such statistics are often skewed, support for joining the USA is strongest among those who don't support the current Prime Minster. People use such polls to express their unhappiness with the current party in power, rather than talk about the actual issues involved.
On the other hand, I can't find any stats on military action, but I'd be fairly sure that Canada would vigorously defend its borders if it were invaded from the South.  Trump can be hard to "read", but I don't see anything in his various comments that suggests he would countenance an invasion. Instead, he would look favourably on a request from the government of Canada to accede to the Union.

I'd be fairly sure that Canada would vigorously defend its borders if it were invaded from the South => I I suspect it would end up like 1968 in Czechoslovakia: lots of low level resistance but a quick capitulation by the government and the military, given what would happen to Canada should a real resistance occur (see: Ukraine). Though I guess it could be much more serious if the U.S. became a banana republic prior to the invasion.

@JonathanReez Meh, this macho talk is soooo pointless and Soldier of Fortune wannabe.  Sure we don't have the direct military muscle, but would we end up like Czechoslovakia?  Or like Afghanistan or Ukraine?  I'd rather not find out and much prefer to truly believe that Americans wouldn't want their country to be like the Soviet Union, with Trump as Putin either.  No matter if the Dems were lame enough to lose this election fair and square due to misreading electoral sentiment.  And for all my dislike of Trump it's hard to see him Putinizing.  Not least cuz he sees direct wars as liabilities.
